# Prevent from Form Post in a devexpress submit button?

Tags: asp.net, button, http-post, devexpress

I have got a dxo submit button. it has a click handler with some logic in it.
my goal is to conditionally prevent it from submitting by putting some logic into the click handler. I have tried a number of JavaScript solutions:
I have tried event.preventDefault() inside the handler, even tried adding another click handler and put the logic inside it but it did not seem to add that handler to the button. I also tried form.unpulish event handler but ended up with the same result.

Update: actually I can do this using form.unpublish event handler. However, I'd prefer to do it via the click handler if possible.

Can anyone have any idea how to tackle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ASPxButton's client-side Click event provides the **e.processOnServer** parameter. You can set it to **False** to cancel the postback. Please try the following:

```
<dxe:ASPxButton ID="ASPxButton1" runat="server" Text="ASPxButton1" OnCommand="ASPxButton1_Command"
    AutoPostBack="true" ClientInstanceName="ASPxButton1">
    <ClientSideEvents Click="
     function(s, e) 
     {
        if (!confirm('add?')) 
        {
            e.processOnServer = false;
        }
    }
}
" />
</dxe:ASPxButton>
```

**References:**
[cancel postback with javascript on aspxbutton](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q133381)
[How avoid the postback when click ASPXButton](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q412710)
[how to prevent postback using the aspxbutton control with clientsideevnts](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q217927)
[ASPxButton - Prevent a server postback in the client-side Click event handler](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T198137)

Comment: Actually I solved the problem using adding another click handler in js file to the button and got it working. But as this works too, I will appreciate it and make it as correct answer.